# Entity Framework - How do I combine data from a database and something else, like WMI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am playing around with writing a simple app that asks the `ServerManager` in `Microsoft.Web.Administration` for a list of web sites configured on the local machine and then combines that with some annotations in some sort of database.

```
namespace ListWebsites.Models
{
    public class Site
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
        public int? Port { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiteDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }

        public void GetSiteInfo()
        {
            using (var server = new ServerManager())
            {
                var siteinfo = from site in server.Sites
                               let bindings = site.Bindings.Select(b => new { host = b.Host, protocol = b.Protocol, port = b.EndPoint?.Port })
                               select new { site.Name, bindings };

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want `ID`, `Comments` to come from a database and `HostName`, `Protocol` and `Port` to come from ServerManager.

My brain is broken trying to figure out what the right way to do this is? Should I combine the data inside the `SiteDbContext` by overriding methods? Should I wrap `SiteDBContext` in something else that joins the data?

I'm kind of a n00b with Entity Framework...maybe I shouldn't be trying to do this with Entity Framework? Not sure how to google the solution for this.

Comment: I wouldn't mix these in DbContext. Instead, I'd query both sets and LINQ join them in a service class.

Comment: so would that be between the controller and model architecturally?  and would the inherited type for the server manager context class be `IObjectContextAdapter` ?

Comment: My preference is to create an entirely new class separate from the controller or model e.g. `SiteInfoService(SiteDbContext, ServerManager)`. Then this can be used in any controller.

Comment: that did the trick.  I got stuff to show on the screen - I think I'm progressing again.  Thanks.